# PowerShell New-ScheduledTaskAction using quotation marks

Tags: powershell

I am having some trouble with creating a scheduled task using PowerShell. The task is to launch Internet Explorer in full screen (iexplore.exe –k).

It’s the “-K” parameter to force it fullscreen that is the problem because the task needs to be like this in Actions: "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" –k (so -k is outside the quotation marks

But obviously I get an error when trying to run:

$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k -Argument "bbc.com"

(New-ScheduledTaskAction : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'k'.)

When I run it like this:

$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -k" -Argument "bbc.com"

It creates the Action as: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe –k which does not work because it needs the quotation marks around C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

The full script is:

$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -k" -Argument "bbc.com"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -TaskName "BBC Test" -Description "BBC Test"

So how do I construct the $Action line so it includes the quotation marks around the “–Execute” parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `-k` not an argument?

Comment: Hi Gert, no, it’s a switch for IE and not an argument for the task action.

Comment: It is a switch, so it is an argument.

Comment: Ok, but I tried it as an argument and it adds -k to the URL (bbc.com -k)

Comment: Hey @IanB , nearly all of your questions you asked on Stack Overflow got answered pretty well. Please don't forget to mark answers as correct (by checking the green hook on the left side of an answer) if they helped you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-K is an (named) argument. It should be in the arguments field of the action

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -Argument "-k bbc.com" 
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "AppLog" -Description "Daily dump of Applog"
```

Comment: Ok great thanks Gert! That worked! And thanks for the explanation! My question is answered, thanks a lot.

Comment: Mmm, order of arguments seem to matter here. I wasn't aware. You are welcome.